# running tcl script via python

Tags: python-2.7, tcl

My Automation script is done using Python and i have to control spirent Testcenter(which supports only tcl). i can communicate with the spirent via Tcl script, if i call the same script via python i get the below error

TCL File - Stc1.tcl

```
package require SpirentTestCenter
source [ file join [ file dirname [ info script ] ] {ipv6_max_session_header.tcl} ]
puts "SpirentTestCenter system version:\t[stc::get system1 -Version]"
```

Python File - tcl_py.py

```
import Tkinter
import os

r=Tkinter.Tk()
r.tk.eval('source Stc_1.tcl')
```

Error that i get -

```
C:\Python27\MyScripts>python tcl_py.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tcl_py.py", line 5, in <module>
    r.tk.eval('source Stc_1.tcl')
_tkinter.TclError: can't find package SpirentTestCenter
```

Comment: If SpirentTestCenter is a stubs enabled package, you might be able to just add the right path where the pkgIndex.tcl file of the package is found to the `::auto_path` variable in Tcl and it might load. But it could be baked into the tcl interpreter too as a static package, a so called bigshell, if that is the case, you cannot (easily) use it in tkinter, short of building tkinter against that Tcl version.

Comment: Can you use subprocess to spawn Stc1.tcl?

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. I was able to execute the TCL script using Python Subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to python subprocess, other thing you could do is open a localhost SSH session in your python script and open tcl shell there (use expect or paramiko shell).

Answer (score 0):

based on the need, there are multiple ways you can use subprocess to run your Tcl Script in python interface. for example, Run command with arguments and return its output.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.check_output("script.tcl", shell=True)
print(p)
```